# wait for beginSheetModalForWindow closes

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, nssavepanel

I have a function which opens NSSavePanel as modalSheet and I need the return to wait after the modal sheet closes, but now it returns immediately as the sheet opens, and if I put the return inside the completion handler it throws an "Unexpected non-void return value in void function".

```
savePanel.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.view.window!, completionHandler: {(result: Int) -> Void in
    ... some code ...
})
return true
```

Comment: You cannot return a value from an asynchronous function. You might put the code which is executed after the function returns into the completion block.